# Semantic-UI 1.6 dropdown input and Angular.JS ng-options

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm using ng-options in the ui dropdown select of Semantic-UI .

The problem is, it's passing ALL the values inside of the Input.

The [screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10926453_911609865538992_9028731077680566383_n.jpg?oh=5c7388578d4d24bad68223244975db80&oe=55280510&__gda__=1428503418_d4b64d1571c7e06a285174e98b792cba)

I've tried using repeat HTML ->

```
<select  ng-model="category" class="ui dropdown">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <option ng-repeat="value in categories" value="1">{{ value.label }}</option>
                </select>
```

And options

```
<select ng-options="value.id as value.label for value in categorias" 
        ng-model="novoAgendamento.category" class="ui dropdown">
                <option value="">Selecionar Categoria</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that you had to wait a long time, in case you've not managed to fix it yet, here's how i do it:

```
<label>Select an item</label>
    <select required 
        class="ui dropdown" 
        ng-model="form.item"
        ng-options="item.id as item.naam for item in items">
    </select>
```

Also, don't forget to initialize the dropdown, by running this piece of code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
    $('.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

I run this piece of code on the controller that belongs to the View which has the dropdowns

(don't forget to inject $rootScope if you wish to do this)